# How to attach GP script tools, standard tools, and Python script to a toolbar?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, add-in

I need to build a custom toolbar that can launch the following items:

- A Python script tool - shouldn't be a problem, as you can already
  attach these to a toolbar
- Out of the box functions such as the Editor Toolbar maybe or a standard GP tool - again, should be do-able as you can already attach these to a toolbar
- A Python script that launches a PyQT/wxPython/Tk GUI. This is the tricky one I think. Now, this GUI does not need to interact with ArcMap. My other custom tools will do all of that, this GUI is for the user to setup parameters that will get written to a XML config file. It will also do some arcpy calls in the background and slurp some data and values out of a geodatabase and push them to the same XML config file.

[image]

So the question is - how to do this as simply as possible? It appears I cannot attach a Python script (that is not encased in a tool) to a toolbar in ArcMap. I'm thinking I'm going to have to go the Add-In route and create a simple Toolbar with buttons to kick off each of the items listed above. VBA is not an option. Thoughts?

Comment: In the What's New in ArcGIS 10.1 available via a link from resources.esri.com it says: "At ArcGIS 10.1, you can program your own buttons and tools using Python add-ins. Python toolboxes are a new kind of toolbox you can create with Python."  These sound like they will help you when that version is released.

Comment: @PolyGeo - Yeah, I know about that, but my client will be on 10.0 for a long time, so waiting around for 10.1 isn't an option either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@ChadCooper, perhaps I'm overlooking something, but with regard to your 3rd case:

> A Python script that launches a PyQT/wxPython/Tk GUI..

Is there a reason why you couldn't use the .Net [Process API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) (see [`System.Diagnostics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx)) to execute your custom Python script over Standard In/Out? Of course, this sort of architecture will assume a proper version of Python is installed and equipped with any additional libs you require. I think you'd just want to extend an `ICommand` object and use the Process API in its `Click()` event. This example (which was an experiment only) called a .py script that used [dbfpy](http://dbfpy.sourceforge.net/) to read the columns in a DBF file and return them as a list to a .Net application.

```
private static List<string> _readDbfOutput;

public static List<string> ReadDbfTable(string dbfPath, int limit)
{
    // start a fresh output object..
    _readDbfOutput = new List<string>();
    _readDbfOutput.Clear();

    // ready..
    string executable = "C:\Python27\python.exe";
    string fullUtilPath = "C:\some_app\utils\read_dbf_table.py";

    // The path to the python file and it's arguments become a single input
    // submitted to the python runtime. In this case, I've got somethign like:
    // C:\>C:/Python27/python.exe C:\some_app\utils\read_dbf_table.py -f C:/data/some_shapefiles.dbf -l 100

    // dbfPath and limit were method arguments..
    string exeArguments = fullUtilPath + " -f " + dbfPath + " -l " + limit.ToString();

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(executable, exeArguments);
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;  // necessary if you need to listen..
    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;  // necessary if you send more inputs..
    startInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;

    Process proc = new Process();

    // ReadingDbfTable is my redirected standard input..
    proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ReadingDbfTable);
    proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
    proc.Start();
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

    // WaitForExit() may need to be wrapped in a Try or Using block.
    // Will it run indefinitely if the script fails?
    proc.WaitForExit();
    proc.Close();

    return _readDbfOutput;
}

/// Handle redirected STDOUT.
private static void ReadingDbfTable(object sendingProc, DataReceivedEventArgs stdOutput)
{
    if ( ! String.IsNullOrEmpty(stdOutput.Data) )
    {
        _readDbfOutput.Add(stdOutput.Data);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very good idea, because if you do it this way the script ALWAYS runs outside of ArcMap, so you only have one environment to test in.

Comment: +1 I was doing something similar to this, but no where near as elegant or functional. I really like the returning of the values from Python back to .NET. One trick with launching a wxPython GUI window though, you have to call `pythonw.exe` to avoid getting a command window. Thanks for the valuable input.